# Spring login Twitter with multiusers

Tags: spring, web

Hi I am a beginner in learning Spring.
I am following the instruction about accessing twitter in Spring website: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-twitter/

But I find a problem that when the first user login the website then the following user can get the first user's information but not login their own account.

I think it needs a multithreading to deal with this problem. Every user can login their own account and the service will preserve each user's connection.

But I don't know how to do it in Spring. Can anybody help me or give a simple example? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring "Accessing Twitter Data tutorial" tutorial has a hardcoded user.  According to the documentation:

*The userIdSource bean is defined by an inner-class that always returns "testuser" as the user ID. The sample application has only one user. In a real application, you probably want to create an implementation of UserIdSource that determines the user ID from the currently authenticated user (perhaps by consulting with an Authentication obtained from Spring Security’s SecurityContext).*

As a result, there is only one user for this example.  Mykong has a good tutorial for setting up spring security for a web page login.  Check out:  http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/